# Highchart rangeSelector is not showing after highchartjs, highchart-ng upgrade

Tags: angular, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have upgraded HighchartsJs to 6.1.0.
So i got compelled to upgrade highchart-ng to latest version(1.2.1).
Also i added polyfill for angular-component and angular-merge because i am using angular-1.3.17.
After the upgrade, rangeSelector which is working on previous versions are not showing now.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FC3qV/106/)

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        allButtonsEnabled: true,
        selected: 2
    },
            navigator: {
      enabled: true,
      adaptToUpdatedData: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature variation by day'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Demo of all buttons enabled. Even though "YTD" and "1y" don\'t apply since we\'re <br>only showing values within one year, they are enabled to allow dynamic interaction'
    },

    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperatures',
        data: data
    }] 
}
```

Comment: Fiddle with angular 1.5.11 - http://jsfiddle.net/jvduycqm/3/

Comment: Shouldn't you use `chartType: 'stock'` to enable this? [From docs](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng#current-version), we have demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jvduycqm/6/

Comment: thanks Pawel.
i missed the point.